# Toggling Leaflet map on click?

Tags: leaflet, display

I have created a Leaflet map on my web page and I would like to show/hide it when I click on a button. When I first load the page, I'd like the map to be hidden.

HTML code:

```
<div class="dropdown" id="gw-dropdown1">
    <button type="button" class="button button--default expandable__button" aria-controls="gw-example-button-dropdown1" aria-expanded="false" id="gw-example-expandable-button1">Select on the map</button>                         
</div>
<div class="map" id="gw_map1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#gw_map1 {
display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#gw-example-expandable-button1").click(function() {
    $("#gw_map1").toggle();
});
```

If I click on the button the map div appears and disappears, but the content of the map is not correctly displayed.

In fact, If I do not set the 'display' into css the map is correctly loaded into the page as in the figure: [image]

but if I set the 'display' to 'none' and then I click on the button the map is displayed incomplete and even if I drag on the map it is always incomplete and polygons are not visible.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: @tom beat me to the answer, but I am guessing you are hiding the div element from the start before the map is created.  It is trying to use a minimum or browser reported size for the hidden element when it is finally displayed.  You changed its size programmatically through JQuery and Leaflet isn't in the loop; you'll have to tell it about the new state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `invalidateSize()` on your map object - this checks if the map container has changed and updates it as necessary.

API reference: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#map-invalidatesize

Answer (score 0):

Create a Leaflet map On QGIS, Its very easy add your data layers to QGIS, set symbology, click on create web map then export leaflet you will get your leaflet on browser where you can manage your layers to show/hide.. For refrence screenshot attached[image: leaflet]

Comment: This does not answer the question since person asking does not mention using QGIS.

Comment: Even if this would answer the question, it would still be not a good answer, since you provide no insight on the processes involved.